# Translate Api/back end error message to display it for user

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, validation, error-handling

I'm working on a form which has both live and front end (javaScript) validation that displays quite nicely. But I also want to display the back end error message to the user for the rare cases the front end validation lets a request pass.

My backend error message is in english atm and I would like some suggestion on how to translate them. I don't want to translate it in the back end.

**Example:**

Back end response:

```
{   "errors": [ {"code": 409, "message" : "An Application has already been created. "}] }
```

Take the "message" and translate the string so I can print it in an element on the page.

**How I'm doing right now:**

```
var ErrorStatusHandler;

ErrorStatusHandler = (function() {
  function ErrorStatusHandler() {}

  ErrorStatusHandler.prototype.errorMessage = function(e) {
    var responseText, translatedResponseText;
    responseText = e.slice(12, -2);
    if (responseText === "An Application has already been created.") {
      translatedResponseText = responseText.replace("An Application has already been created.", "En ansökan med detta personnummer existerar redan.");
    } else {
//* some other error
      translatedResponseText = responseText;
    }
    return translatedResponseText;
  };

  return ErrorStatusHandler;

})();
```

But I'm sure that there is a better way to do this, I just cant seem to find one. 
P.S I rather not use a plugin, but if there isn't any good solutions I might have to.

Comment: why not use a translation file like:
{"An Application has already been created.":"En ansökan med detta personnummer existerar redan.","foo":"bar} etc. Also you might add paramaters that do not get translated

Comment: That actually sound like a good suggestion. Do you have a link to some documentations on how the best practice is? Thanks!

Comment: What is the parameter `e` in your code. The way I see it is you don't need to do fancy moves like `e.slice` especially when you can `JSON.parse(e)` and then access your response text as `var errors = JSON.parse(e);` and then use `errors[0].message`

Comment: the e parameter is the message object: `{"message":"An Application has already been created."}`. Ohh okay, Ill look into it. Thanks

Comment: I just checked, both JSON.parse(e) and e logs the same. e: `{"message":"An Application has already been created."} JSON.parse(e): Object {message: "An Application has already been created."}. And i use the slice to get rid of all the brackets and semicolons.

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery `$.ajax()` you can achieve using `statusCode:` handler, for each of the status codes your api will return back to client, you can have `statusCode` handler to handle them. like this for 404

*Ref:http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/*

**JS CODE:**

```
$.ajax({
  statusCode: {
    404: function() {
       alert( "page not found" );
    }
  }
});
```

Also you can handle the status codes in your `error:` callback handler of your ajax call,[Check here @ JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chufol/SrQqP/)

Comment: Yeah, I know its possible, but the reason I made a separate class to handle it was to avoid having ~20 translated error messages on each request. 
Edit: might have misunderstood you.

Comment: Does that mean your making successive ajax calls & need a generic method  to handle it. i think you can still achieve it by calling a external method with current `status code` if any & handle it there.

Comment: No, the ajax call returns as error. And I have a set of different e.thrown from the backend depending on what went wrong. They all are in English, and I just want a way to translate them to another language and display them for the user.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way to do it.

```
var errorMessages = {
    'en':{
        '409':'An Application has already been created.'
        '404':'Not Found'
    },
    'fr':{
        '409':'En ansökan med detta personnummer existerar redan.'
        '404':'Frogs are not only the proof that french people will put anything into their mouths, but also they are amphibians'
    }
};
var currentLanguage = 'fr';
var ErrorStatusHandler;

ErrorStatusHandler = (function() {
  function ErrorStatusHandler() {}

  ErrorStatusHandler.prototype.errorMessage = function(e) {
    var responseText, translatedResponseText;
    //responseText = e.slice(12, -2); - not sure if this is required
    var response = JSON.parse(e); //assuming e is your response.
    var errors = response.errors;
    translatedResponseText = errorMessages[currentLanguage][errors[0].code];
    return translatedResponseText;
  };

  return ErrorStatusHandler;

})();
```

Explanation:

The object `errorMessages` holds the translation of message for each `code`.
Then you set your current language in `currentLanguage` varible.

When your response is received, you parse it to a JS object with `JSON.parse()`
And then use the traslated string based on your `code`'s value.

Comment: Yes but this would make my requests HUGE, since I want to translate ~20 error messages.

Comment: Don't put the translation in your `response`. maintain the translations object on client.

Comment: hmmm, in that case i would suggest you to use some plugins for that at the client side,else things will get messy when you need to handle the error messages in different languages in future

Comment: Thats what I've been trying to avoid. But I guess I might have too. Any suggestions on good plugins?

Comment: For me this plugin looks good , http://tympanus.net/codrops/2009/11/30/jtexttranslate-a-jquery-translation-plugin/ and the quality of translation looks good

Comment: @hevar: if you have found the answer , can we close this question